# Cannot install Tensorflow in R, "could not find a Python environment for {PATH}"

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to install Tensorflow's GPU acceleration for R onto my PC. I once used the Intel distro for Python which includes the commonly used scientific libraries and I never really used it as I am an R user but it somehow permanently destroyed my computer's ability to have a functioning copy of Python, as in I cannot for some reason properly install libraries. I have Python on my PC right now but I'm not sure if it works or not as it's my one millionth reinstallation of it.

That aside, I am trying to install Keras for R and I'm encountering some issues.

When I run:

```
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow(version = "gpu")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find a Python environment for C:\Users\{my name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

I checked that directory and `python.exe` indeed exists, so I'm not sure what's the problem. I'm worried I have haphazardly destroyed some low-level files in a way that prevents me from ever using Python on my installation of Windows ever again. Uninstalling and reinstalling Python doesn't work.

Do you have any recommendations?

EDIT: Following the user installation page:

```
> library(tensorflow)
> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/artas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/artas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python39.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/artas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39
version:        3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

EDIT 2: I followed @jwarz's advice but now I get this error:

```
> tensorflow::install_tensorflow(version = "gpu")
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tensorflow', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\artas\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 19, in _import_hook
    module = _import(
  File "C:\Users\artas\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 19, in _import_hook
    module = _import(
```

I took the extra step of installing Keras into the conda environment.

```
> reticulate::conda_install(packages = "tensorflow")
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\artas\MINICO~1\envs\r-reticulate

  added / updated specs:
    - python
    - tensorflow


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    absl-py-0.11.0             |   py37h03978a9_0         169 KB  conda-forge
    astor-0.8.1                |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          25 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2020.12.5  |       h5b45459_0         173 KB  conda-forge
    cached-property-1.5.1      |             py_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2020.12.5          |   py37h03978a9_0         143 KB  conda-forge
    gast-0.4.0                 |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    google-pasta-0.2.0         |     pyh8c360ce_0          42 KB  conda-forge
    grpcio-1.34.0              |   py37h04d2302_0         1.8 MB  conda-forge
    h5py-3.1.0                 |nompi_py37h19fda09_100        1009 KB  conda-forge
    hdf5-1.10.6                |nompi_he0bbb20_101        19.4 MB  conda-forge
    importlib-metadata-3.3.0   |   py37h03978a9_2          21 KB  conda-forge
    intel-openmp-2020.3        |     h57928b3_311         2.0 MB  conda-forge
    keras-applications-1.0.8   |             py_1          30 KB  conda-forge
    keras-preprocessing-1.1.0  |             py_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    libblas-3.9.0              |            5_mkl         3.9 MB  conda-forge
    libcblas-3.9.0             |            5_mkl         3.9 MB  conda-forge
    liblapack-3.9.0            |            5_mkl         3.9 MB  conda-forge
    libprotobuf-3.14.0         |       h7755175_0         2.3 MB  conda-forge
    m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0|                6         342 KB  conda-forge
    m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0       |                7         520 KB  conda-forge
    m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0  |                7         214 KB  conda-forge
    m2w64-gmp-6.1.0            |                2         726 KB  conda-forge
    m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757|                2          31 KB  conda-forge
    markdown-3.3.3             |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          66 KB  conda-forge
    mkl-2020.4                 |     hb70f87d_311       172.4 MB  conda-forge
    msys2-conda-epoch-20160418 |                1           3 KB  conda-forge
    numpy-1.19.4               |   py37hd20adf4_1         4.8 MB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.1.1i             |       h8ffe710_0         5.8 MB  conda-forge
    protobuf-3.14.0            |   py37hf2a7229_0         261 KB  conda-forge
    pyreadline-2.1             |py37hc8dfbb8_1002         146 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.7.9               |h7840368_0_cpython        17.9 MB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.7             |          1_cp37m           4 KB  conda-forge
    scipy-1.6.0                |   py37h6db1a17_0        23.2 MB  conda-forge
    setuptools-49.6.0          |   py37hf50a25e_2         919 KB  conda-forge
    six-1.15.0                 |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    tensorboard-1.14.0         |           py37_0         3.2 MB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-1.14.0          |       h1f41ff6_0          23 KB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-base-1.14.0     |   py37hc8dfbb8_0        57.3 MB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0|   py37h5ca1d4c_0         646 KB  conda-forge
    termcolor-1.1.0            |             py_2           6 KB  conda-forge
    typing_extensions-3.7.4.3  |             py_0          25 KB  conda-forge
    werkzeug-1.0.1             |     pyh9f0ad1d_0         239 KB  conda-forge
    wincertstore-0.2           |py37hc8dfbb8_1005          15 KB  conda-forge
    wrapt-1.12.1               |   py37hcc03f2d_2          46 KB  conda-forge
    zipp-3.4.0                 |             py_0          11 KB  conda-forge
    zlib-1.2.11.1              |   vc14ha0a531f_3         378 KB  intel
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       327.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  absl-py            conda-forge/win-64::absl-py-0.11.0-py37h03978a9_0
  astor              conda-forge/noarch::astor-0.8.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  ca-certificates    conda-forge/win-64::ca-certificates-2020.12.5-h5b45459_0
  cached-property    conda-forge/noarch::cached-property-1.5.1-py_0
  gast               conda-forge/noarch::gast-0.4.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  google-pasta       conda-forge/noarch::google-pasta-0.2.0-pyh8c360ce_0
  grpcio             conda-forge/win-64::grpcio-1.34.0-py37h04d2302_0
  h5py               conda-forge/win-64::h5py-3.1.0-nompi_py37h19fda09_100
  hdf5               conda-forge/win-64::hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_he0bbb20_101
  importlib-metadata conda-forge/win-64::importlib-metadata-3.3.0-py37h03978a9_2
  intel-openmp       conda-forge/win-64::intel-openmp-2020.3-h57928b3_311
  keras-applications conda-forge/noarch::keras-applications-1.0.8-py_1
  keras-preprocessi~ conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_0
  libblas            conda-forge/win-64::libblas-3.9.0-5_mkl
  libcblas           conda-forge/win-64::libcblas-3.9.0-5_mkl
  liblapack          conda-forge/win-64::liblapack-3.9.0-5_mkl
  libprotobuf        conda-forge/win-64::libprotobuf-3.14.0-h7755175_0
  m2w64-gcc-libgfor~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6
  m2w64-gcc-libs     conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gcc-libs-co~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gmp          conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2
  m2w64-libwinpthre~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2
  markdown           conda-forge/noarch::markdown-3.3.3-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  mkl                conda-forge/win-64::mkl-2020.4-hb70f87d_311
  msys2-conda-epoch  conda-forge/win-64::msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1
  numpy              conda-forge/win-64::numpy-1.19.4-py37hd20adf4_1
  protobuf           conda-forge/win-64::protobuf-3.14.0-py37hf2a7229_0
  pyreadline         conda-forge/win-64::pyreadline-2.1-py37hc8dfbb8_1002
  scipy              conda-forge/win-64::scipy-1.6.0-py37h6db1a17_0
  six                conda-forge/noarch::six-1.15.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  tensorboard        conda-forge/win-64::tensorboard-1.14.0-py37_0
  tensorflow         conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-1.14.0-h1f41ff6_0
  tensorflow-base    conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-base-1.14.0-py37hc8dfbb8_0
  tensorflow-estima~ conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0-py37h5ca1d4c_0
  termcolor          conda-forge/noarch::termcolor-1.1.0-py_2
  typing_extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py_0
  werkzeug           conda-forge/noarch::werkzeug-1.0.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  wrapt              conda-forge/win-64::wrapt-1.12.1-py37hcc03f2d_2
  zipp               conda-forge/noarch::zipp-3.4.0-py_0
  zlib               intel/win-64::zlib-1.2.11.1-vc14ha0a531f_3

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  openssl              intel::openssl-1.1.1h-vc14he774522_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1i-h8ffe710_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  certifi                          2020.12.5-py39hcbf5309_0 --> 2020.12.5-py37h03978a9_0
  python                           3.9.1-h7840368_1_cpython --> 3.7.9-h7840368_0_cpython
  python_abi                                     3.9-1_cp39 --> 3.7-1_cp37m
  setuptools                          49.6.0-py39h467e6f4_2 --> 49.6.0-py37hf50a25e_2
  wincertstore                        0.2-py39hde42818_1005 --> 0.2-py37hc8dfbb8_1005



Downloading and Extracting Packages
liblapack-3.9.0      | 3.9 MB    | ########## | 100% 
m2w64-gcc-libs-core- | 214 KB    | ########## | 100% 
typing_extensions-3. | 25 KB     | ########## | 100% 
six-1.15.0           | 14 KB     | ########## | 100% 
zipp-3.4.0           | 11 KB     | ########## | 100% 
gast-0.4.0           | 12 KB     | ########## | 100% 
openssl-1.1.1i       | 5.8 MB    | ########## | 100% 
importlib-metadata-3 | 21 KB     | ########## | 100% 
grpcio-1.34.0        | 1.8 MB    | ########## | 100% 
absl-py-0.11.0       | 169 KB    | ########## | 100% 
ca-certificates-2020 | 173 KB    | ########## | 100% 
tensorflow-1.14.0    | 23 KB     | ########## | 100% 
tensorflow-estimator | 646 KB    | ########## | 100% 
intel-openmp-2020.3  | 2.0 MB    | ########## | 100% 
m2w64-libwinpthread- | 31 KB     | ########## | 100% 
werkzeug-1.0.1       | 239 KB    | ########## | 100% 
libcblas-3.9.0       | 3.9 MB    | ########## | 100% 
h5py-3.1.0           | 1009 KB   | ########## | 100% 
keras-applications-1 | 30 KB     | ########## | 100% 
hdf5-1.10.6          | 19.4 MB   | ########## | 100% 
wincertstore-0.2     | 15 KB     | ########## | 100% 
msys2-conda-epoch-20 | 3 KB      | ########## | 100% 
astor-0.8.1          | 25 KB     | ########## | 100% 
tensorflow-base-1.14 | 57.3 MB   | ########## | 100% 
python-3.7.9         | 17.9 MB   | ########## | 100% 
python_abi-3.7       | 4 KB      | ########## | 100% 
m2w64-gcc-libgfortra | 342 KB    | ########## | 100% 
tensorboard-1.14.0   | 3.2 MB    | ########## | 100% 
numpy-1.19.4         | 4.8 MB    | ########## | 100% 
cached-property-1.5. | 10 KB     | ########## | 100% 
zlib-1.2.11.1        | 378 KB    | ########## | 100% 
scipy-1.6.0          | 23.2 MB   | ########## | 100% 
protobuf-3.14.0      | 261 KB    | ########## | 100% 
libprotobuf-3.14.0   | 2.3 MB    | ########## | 100% 
m2w64-gmp-6.1.0      | 726 KB    | ########## | 100% 
mkl-2020.4           | 172.4 MB  | ########## | 100% 
wrapt-1.12.1         | 46 KB     | ########## | 100% 
libblas-3.9.0        | 3.9 MB    | ########## | 100% 
termcolor-1.1.0      | 6 KB      | ########## | 100% 
markdown-3.3.3       | 66 KB     | ########## | 100% 
keras-preprocessing- | 33 KB     | ########## | 100% 
setuptools-49.6.0    | 919 KB    | ########## | 100% 
google-pasta-0.2.0   | 42 KB     | ########## | 100% 
certifi-2020.12.5    | 143 KB    | ########## | 100% 
m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0 | 520 KB    | ########## | 100% 
pyreadline-2.1       | 146 KB    | ########## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
```

The installation was successful but I am still getting the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have RStudio 1.4.1038, which is the advance version that allows you to set your Python version in the Global Options, so there was a conflict between what I wanted and what the reticulate-integrated RStudio setting dictated. That was it. I was being unnecessarily apocalyptic.

Comment: It is worth noting that in the Python entry in Global Options _all_ python interpreters are shown available on your machine, including virtualenv and (mini)conda-envs.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the package manager conda / miniconda for your python version. After that, execute the following steps in the correct order:

```r
reticulate::use_condaenv("/your/path/to/miniconda3-4.7.12/")
reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-reticulate")
reticulate::use_condaenv("/your/path/to/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/r-reticulate")

# Verify if it was properly selected
reticulate::py_config()
## python:         /your/path/to/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
## ... 

# tensorflow::install_tensorflow(version = "gpu")

# To install Keras
keras::install_keras(method = 'conda', envname = 'r-reticulate')
keras::is_keras_available()
```

Comment: I updated my post in response to your answer.

Comment: Did `reticulate::py_config()` show the proper python location? If yes, you can install Keras with the commands from my edited answer.

Comment: No, `py_config()` still shows me my default python path, not the one to my conda installation. I'm seriously considering either dual-booting Ubuntu or reinstalling Windows.